# Using inotify to monitor a directory but not working 100%

Tags: shell, shell-script, inotify

I have written a bash script to monitor a particular directory `/root/secondfolder/`:

```
#!/bin/sh

while inotifywait -mr -e close_write "/root/secondfolder/"
do
    echo "close_write"
done
```

When I create a file called `fourth.txt` in `/root/secondfolder/` and write stuff to it, save and close it, it outputs the following:

```
/root/secondfolder/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE fourth.txt
```

However, it does not echo "close_write". Why is that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`inotifywait -m` [is "monitor" mode](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait): it never exits. The shell runs it and waits for the exit code to know whether to run the body of the loop, but that never comes.

If you remove `-m`, it will work:

```
while inotifywait -r -e close_write "/root/secondfolder/"
do
    echo "close_write"
done
```

produces

```
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
/root/secondfolder/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE bar
close_write
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
...
```

By default, inotifywait will "exit after the first event occurs", which is what you want in a loop condition.

---

Instead, you might prefer to read the standard output of `inotifywait`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    echo "close_write: $line"
done < <(inotifywait -mr -e close_write "/tmp/test/")
```

This (bash) script will read each output line of the `inotifywait` command into the `$line` variable inside the loop, using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution). It avoids setting up the recursive watches every time around the loop, which might be expensive. If you can't use bash, you can pipe the command into the loop instead: `inotifywait ... | while read line ...`. `inotifywait` produces one line of output for each event in this mode, so the loop runs once for each.

Comment: Piping the command into the loop works, thanks!