# Check whether a file is opened or not

Tags: shell-script, shell, inotify

I have a folder, inside of which there are a lot of files. I was looking for a way to check whether any file inside that folder has been opened or not. If it is open, I need to get notified. I know this can be done using inotify-wait but have not been able to do so.

Here is my script

```
MONITORDIR="/home/aniketshivamtiwari/Downloads/Projects"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" | while read NEWFILE
do
        echo  "File ${NEWFILE} has been opened" 
done
```

Comment: Closely related: [Using inotify to monitor a directory but not working 100%](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140679/73093)

Comment: Why do you use `create` and not `open` if what you want is to monitor wheter files inside the directory are opened? Couldn't you use something  like this instead: `inotifywait -m -q -e open --format '%w%f' ${MONITORDIR}/*`?

Comment: @Rastapopoulos - Your solution  worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As suggested by Rastapopoulos in the comments** Here is the solution
First install **sudo apt-get install inotify-tools**

```
MONITORDIR="path/to/the/folder"
inotifywait -m -q -e open --format '%w%f' ${MONITORDIR}/* | while read NEWFILE
do
        echo   "File ${NEWFILE} has been open" 
done
```